# Show that for any classes $\mathbf A, \mathbf B: \mathbf B - (\mathbf A - \mathbf B) = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book *set theory and the continuum problem* the following definition is given:

$\mathbf A - \mathbf B$  means the class of all sets $x$ such that
$x \in \mathbf A$ and $x \notin \mathbf B$

you are then asked to show that for any classes  $\mathbf A, \mathbf B, ...:$
$$\mathbf B - (\mathbf A - \mathbf B) = \emptyset $$

I can't get this to work out in my head:

if:

$\mathbf A - \mathbf B$ = $\mathbf A \cap {\mathbf B^c}$ where ${\mathbf B^c}$ is the complement of $\mathbf B$

then:

$$\mathbf B - (\mathbf A - \mathbf B) = \mathbf B \cap {(\mathbf A \cap {\mathbf B^c})}^c$$

$$\mathbf B \cap {(\mathbf A \cap {\mathbf B^c})}^c = \mathbf B \cap \mathbf B$$

I don't see how $\mathbf B - (\mathbf A - \mathbf B) = \emptyset $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\{1,2,3\} \text{ and } B=\{3,4,5\}.$$ Then $$A-B=\{1,2\},$$ but $$B-(A-B)=\{3,4,5\} \neq \emptyset.$$

In fact,
$$B-(A-B)=B \cap (A \cap B^c)^c=B \cap (A^c \cup B)=(B\cap A^c) \cup B=B.$$

Alternatively, since $B \cap (A-B) = \emptyset$, therefore $B-(A-B)=B$.

Comment: Right! So should I take it that its a typo? Since $B-(A-B) \neq \emptyset $

Comment: Yes, $B - (A -B) = \emptyset \iff B = \emptyset.$